# How to map keys for IdeaVim's normal mode to editor's action?

Tags: vim, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm, ideavim

I am using JetBrains' phpstorm with the IdeaVim plugin.

I am wondering if I can bind keys in normal mode to editor actions.

For example, I used to have mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to Navigate > Declaration. Yet <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> is a vi motion to go one page backwards and that is ok.

I know I can configure a keyboard shortcut to a different one, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> , yet to keep things simpler I want to have a key in ideavim's command mode mapped to that functionality, e.g. `;`.

So that pressing ; in command mode would trigger the action of `Declaration` witin phpstorm.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 14):

To give a specific answer for exactly what you asked to map: put this into your `~/.ideavimrc`:

```
nnoremap ; :action VimGotoDeclaration<CR>
```

To find the action name, I typed `:actionlist declaration` which gives a subset of action names that include the word "declaration" in the action name.

As others have noted, you might also prefer to use one of the existing mappings rather than adding a new one.

Comment: I feared it wasn't possible, so glad it is!

Answer (score 3):

what you wanted `go to declaration` is built in command in vim. You don't have to use IDEA's actions.

`gd` (**g**oto **d**eclaration) is the thing you are looking for.

So you just press (normal mode) `gd`, to see what is gonna happen.

In a normal vim, do `:h gd` to check details.

Comment: While this works for the action described in the questioin, would you know how to remap a key to some other editor action?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<C-]>` (Ctrl+]) for following references (jumping to the declaration is an example of a reference) and `<C-O>` for going back. You can also map these Vim-style shortcuts using the `map` commands similar to the original Vim.